# Netty 10000 connections at the same time

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to simulate a 10000 client connection at the same time to server using Netty. When 956 clients connect to the server everything work great, but the 957 client cause an error exception.

Note: I am running the server and the clients at the same machine(win7 8GB ram, i7-CPU)

The error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
```

My code:

```
try {
        con.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Client: error connect to ip {} and port {}, ",id, ip, port,e);
        return;
    }
```

The code of `connect` method is:

```
public void connect() {
    workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    Bootstrap bs = new Bootstrap();
    bs.group(workerGroup).channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
    bs.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 300));
            ch.pipeline().addLast("idleStateActionHandler", new IdleStateEventHandler());
            ch.pipeline().addLast("logger", new LoggingHandler());
            ch.pipeline().addLast("commandDecoder", new CommandDecoder());
            ch.pipeline().addLast("commandEncoder", new CommandEncoder());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Windows is quite restrictive in the number of ephemeral ports it allows to be opened by default. I suggest checking that setting first. (Google it, I forgot the details).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the same NioEventLoopGroup instance for each connect call. Otherwise you will create a lot of Threads.

Comment: If i use the same NioEventLoopGroup instance it wouldn't be the same as real system.

Comment: @Alexbelenko You have a "real system" that runs 10,000 threads at once on one machine? I would advise you to listen to Norman and re-think your test. Assuming you are stress testing the server, what should it matter what the test clients look like as long as they send realistic sequences of messages?

Comment: Yes our current system is 2 servers, each one can handle 5000 clients, there is more than 4000 clients for each server.